# Heroku with Multiple Domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github

I have multiple heroku domains. After I created a new one, and I pushed, it checked the rsa for the first one.

How to handle this? Thanks.

203-96:first_app marklaudalauw$ heroku create
Creating serene-chamber-4301... done, stack is cedar
http://serene-chamber-4301.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:serene-chamber-4301.git

203-96:first_app marklaudalauw$ git push heroku master

!  Your key with fingerprint 98:6b:fe:d4:e3:0a:17:16:ab:f8:11:18:a2:66:76:b6 is not authorized to access glacial-shelf-8147.

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: check for the heroku logs it will show what is causing the error. also make sure you read the heroku document full before deploying the your code

Answer (score 0):

Before pushing Try this:-

```
$ git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:yourappname.git  ( to add current stack )

$ heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (if stuck with key then add local machine key to heroku) 

$ git commit -m "message"

$ git push heroku master <branch name>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by the following commands:

git remote rm heroku

git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:serene-chamber-4301.git

Thanks...